# How to convert curl actions in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, curl

curl action like:

```
curl -XPOST http://api.zoomeye.org/user/login -d
'{
    "username": "foo@bar.com",
    "password": "foobar"
}'
```

I want to implement it in iOS, So i try

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"username" : username,
                             @"password" : password
                             };
AFHTTPSessionManager *mgr = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[mgr POST:@"http://api.zoomeye.org/user/login" parameters:user success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"work");  //test
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"Error");  //test
}];
```

But i always get the Error.

How can i convert it?

Comment: it just go to the failure block

Comment: So log `error`. What does it say?

Comment: Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)"

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solve this by myself.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.zoomeye.org/user/login"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
[request setHTTPBody:postdata];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];


NSLog(@"%@",dic);
```

and i get the right response.